# How can I disable Crashlytics at runtime in response to a user preference change?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I would like to provide a setting in my Android app's settings activity allowing the user to disable our use of analytics software, including Crashlytics. However, `Crashlytics.start(Context)` is called long before the user gets to the settings page, and I don't see an equivalent `Crashlytics.stop(Context)` function. Is it possible to stop Crashlytics within the app after it has been started?

Comment: You can consider user's choice on the next app start and skip the initialization. For the current app session he will have the crashlytics enabled. Do you think this is a big issue for the users?

Comment: Since this is a Privacy-related concern, I believe it's disingenuous to not have the preference change take effect immediately. Our users will definitely care if data is sent to 3rd parties when they've specifically requested it not be.

Comment: Could you not firce app to exit by doing a system.exit(0) after setting the flag (which is checked at startup) and telling user to restart the app? Not great but will force crashlytics to effectively disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been informed that the specific case I'm attempting is not currently possible. However, I can give users control over whether or not to send data to Crashlytics by enabling the "Privacy prompt" in the App settings part of the Crashlytics dashboard:

> [Go here](http://crashlytics.com/settings/apps) to select the app you want to add the dialog to and then click on "Enable Privacy Prompt" in the top left corner.

from: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#using-the-privacy-dialog

Comment: Then the user will be asked everytime a crash occured, or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do.

1. Add a preference to your app settings and let the user descide wether he want do it or not.
2. Implement UncaughtExceptionHandler and do like this

```
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());

        Boolean send = sharedPref.getBoolean(MySettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SEND_ERROR, true);

        if (send) {
            orgHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics cannot be stopped once started but the behaviour you want can be reached via overriding the default UncaughtExceptionHandler:

```
    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler crashlyticsExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
        if (isAnalyticsAllowed) {
            crashlyticsExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        } else {
            defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    });
```